# c++: vector of vector issue

Tags: c++, vector, push, back

I wrote a c++ code where i'm testing the running time of vector push_back. I have a vector of vector. I called my main vector, mainVec, and embedded vector, subVec. So, I push backed 2^20 elements into subVec and then push backed subVec 2^20 times into mainVec. However, in the loop of subVec-push_back I have a cout command which doesn't get executed. I was hoping you can point out my mistake.

Here is the code (There is no error in the code, though):

```
vector<int> subVec; 
vector< vector<int> > mainVec;

//Fills the subvector with 2^20 elements
for( size_t i = 0; i < (pow(2,20)+1); ++i) subVec.push_back(i);

//Filling of the maiVec with 2^20 subVec
for( size_t j = 10; j < 21; ++j) {
    cout << pow(2,j) << endl;
    clock_t t1 = clock();

    //2^j times subVec is push_backed for j < 21
    for( size_t k = 0; k < pow(2,j); ++k ) mainVec.push_back( subVec );

    t1 = clock()-t1;

    //Outputting to file
    cout << "\t" << (float(t1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << endl;
    //ofs << pow(2,j) << "\t\t" << (float(t1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why 2^20? Does the `cout` work correctly for 2^20-1? *Simplify.*

Comment: 2^20 vectors of 2^20 ints?  You have over 4 terabytes of memory?

Comment: Lol Nevermind guys. I changed my program to only two loops. Second one goes up to 2^8.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code.

First, you don't need the `+1` in the first loop, i.e,. `pow(2,20)+1`. Since you're starting with 0 and you want 2^20 times, you need to do until `i<2^20`.

Second, it's better to calculate the `pow`s before the loop, otherwise it will calculate them each time and that could take forever.

Third, you can do `1<<j` instead of `pow(2,j)`. Just FYI.

Forth, and most important, we are talking about a tremenduous amount of memory here. Even your smallest loop is doing 2^30 ints which is 4GB of memory. My guess is that your program is just killing your computer and the reason it never prints the second `cout` is that it doesn't get there (because it's trying to use swap file for the memory). Try using smaller numbers, say 2^10 for the first loop, and see if you get the outputs.

Comment: Thanks, I don't care about the time it takes for the program to calculate pow because i'm not interested in that. I'm only interested in the time it takes to push_back subVec.

Comment: But your comment was helpful. I only have two loops now with second loop being less than 2^8 which i think is still huge lol

Comment: @Cheetahjimi 2^8 is only 256, that's tiny. But how big is the first loop? Is it still 2^20? If so try making it 2^10. Just to see if you get the output.